# Sending content of a file a message using AWS SES

Tags: amazon-web-services, email, amazon-ses

I want to send content of a text file as a message using aws ses. 
The below command works fine. But I don't know how to replace the message section of my json with the contents of a file.

aws ses send-email --from "subit.das@gmail.com" --destination "ToAddresses=subit.das@gmail.com" --message "Subject={Data=from ses,Charset=utf8},Body={Text={Data= ses says hi,Charset=utf8},Html={Data=,Charset=utf8}}"

aws ses send-email --from subit.das@gmail.com --destination file://destination.json --message file://message.json

The message.json is like below

```
{
```

"Simple": {
    "Subject": {
      "Data": "string",
      "Charset": "string"
    },
    "Body": {
      "Text": {
        "Data": "Dev deployment complete",
        "Charset": "string"
      },
    }
  },
  "Raw": {
    "Data": blob
  },
  "Template": {
    "TemplateArn": "string",
    "TemplateData": "string"
  }
}

I want to update the data section.

Comment: Have you tried the `--text` / `--html` option?

Comment: No, can you please share me a link

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ses/send-email.html let me know if that helped and I'll add it as an answer :)